# ASP.NET MVVM Handling multiple Data Transfer Objects on a single page

Tags: asp.net, mvc

I have an asp.net mvc "edit" page which allows the user to make edits to the parent entity, and then also "create" child entities on the same page. Note: I'm making these data transfer objects up.

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public etc..
    public CustomerOrderCreateViewModel CustomerOrderCreateViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

In my view I have two html form's. One for Customer "edit" Http Posts, and the other for CustomerOrder "create" Http Posts. In the view page, I load the CustomerOrder "create" form in using:

```
<div id="CustomerOrderCreate">
    @Html.Partial("Vendor/_CustomerOrderCreatePartial", Model.CustomerOrderCreateViewModel)
</div>
```

The CustomerOrder html form action posts to a different controller HttpPost ActionResult than the Customer "edit" Action Result.

My concern is this, on the CustomerOrder controller, in the HttpPost ActionResult

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CustomerOrderCreateViewModel vm)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return [What Do I Return Here]
    }
    ...[Persist to database code]...
}
```

I don't know what to return if the model state isn't valid. Right now it's not a problem, because jquery unobtrusive validation handles validation on the client. But what if I need more complex validation (ie: the server needs to handle the validation).

Answer (score 3):

Well, it *is* a problem now because you can't trust jQuery to do your validation for you.  You can't trust anything on the client because it's not really under your control.  You have to validate everything on the server, even if you're doing it client-side just to be slick.

What you call a `ViewModel` is what I like to call the `EditModel`.  That is, a flattened representation of the `Model` that can be in an invalid state.  Your server needs to be able to translate from a `ViewModel` DTO to the `Model` and back again, but it also needs to have the validation logic to check the `ViewModel` before it performs the conversion.

So when you submit the DTO to the server, you always get back another `ViewModel`.  In the case where it was a success, you get back your new `ViewModel` with the edits applied, or if it was unsuccessful maybe you get back a `ViewModel` that has validation errors.  The page has to display those  validation errors.  Those errors have to be in the `ViewModel` either as fields, or as a collection of validation messages that get displayed in a pop-down or something.